# Frama-C code slicer not loading any C files

Tags: c, slice, frama-c

I have a 1000 lines C file with 10 maths algorithms written by a professor, I need to delete 9 maths functions and all their dependencies from the 1000 lines, so i am having a go using Frama-C Boron windows binary installer.

Now it won't load the simplest example.c file... i select source file and nothing loads.

Boron edition is from 2010 so i checked how to compile a later Frama-C: they say having a space in my windows 7 user name can cause problems, which is not encouraging.

Is Frama-C my best option for my slicing task?

Here is an example file that won't load:

```
    // File swap.c:

    /*@ requires \valid(a) && \valid(b);
      @ ensures A: *a == \old(*b) ;
      @ ensures B: *b == \old(*a) ;
      @ assigns *a,*b ;
      @*/
    void swap(int *a,int *b)
    {
      int tmp = *a ;
      *a = *b ;
      *b = tmp ;
      return ;
    }
```

Here is the code i wish to take only one function from, the option labelled smooth and swvd. https://sites.google.com/site/kootsoop/Home/cohens_class_code

Comment: Did I get this right: you want to remove every function from a file that is not (transitively) called from a single function? How many functions are in that file? Is it really unpractical to do this manually?

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes i was going to do it manually if there is no way to do it otherwise. It would be so easy for a machine to underline unrelated code, i was hoping to save some hours of work on it, i have to be familiar with a fast C compiler, can it be compiled as a stand alone C file? so i can have error warnings?

Comment: I added the C code to the original post if you can see, will it compile as a single C file and is it easy to unweave? (unweave haha )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the code you linked to, and it does not seem like the best candidate for a Frama-C analysis. For instance, that code is not strictly C99-conforming, using e.g. some old-style prototypes (including implicit `int` return types), functions that are used before they are defined without forward declarations (`fft`), and a missing header inclusion (`stdlib.h`). Those are not big issues, since the changes are relatively simple, and some of them are treated similarly to how `gcc -std=c99` works: they emit warnings but not errors. However, it's important to notice that they do require a non-zero amount of time, therefore this won't be a "plug-and-play" solution.

On a more general note, Frama-C relies on [CIL (C Intermediate Language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Intermediate_Language) for C code normalization, so the sliced program will probably not be identical to "the original program minus the sliced statements". If the objective is merely to remove some statements but keep the code syntactically identical otherwise, then Frama-C will not be ideal<sup>1</sup>.

Finally, it is worth noting that some Frama-C analyses can help finding dead code, and the result is even clearer if the code is already split into functions. For instance, using Value analysis on a properly configured program, it is possible to see which statements/functions are never executed. But this does rely on the absence of at least some kinds of undefined behavior.

E.g. if uninitialized variables are used in your program (which is forbidden by the C standard, but occasionally happens and goes unnoticed), the Value analysis will stop its propagation and the code afterwards may be marked as dead, since it is *semantically* dead w.r.t. the standard. It's important to be aware of that, since a naive approach would be misleading.

Overall, for the code size you mention, I'm not sure Frama-C would be a cost-effective approach, especially if (1) you have never used Frama-C and are having trouble compiling it (Boron is a really old release, not recommended) and (2) if you already know your code base, and therefore would be relatively proficient in manually slicing its parts.

<sup>1</sup>*That said, I do not know of any C slicer that preserves statements like that; my point is that, while intuitively one might think that a C slicer would straightforwardly preserve most of the syntax, C is such a devious language that doing so is very hard, hence why most tools will do some normalization steps beforehand.*